# cannot access ExternalResource when calling MockWebServer

Tags: spring-boot, webclient, mockwebserver, spring-webclient

I am having trouble getting [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) working. I added the dependency to build.gradle

**testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.2.0'**

I have the following class (I copied from here https://codingtim.github.io/webclient-testing/)

```
public class ApiCaller {

private WebClient webClient;

ApiCaller(WebClient webClient) {
    this.webClient = webClient;
}

Mono<String> callApi() {
    return webClient.put()
            .uri("/api/resource")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Authorization", "customAuth")
            .syncBody(new String())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(SimpleResponseDto.class);
    }
}
```

My test class looks like this

```
public class ApiCallerTest {

private final MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
private final ApiCaller apiCaller = new ApiCaller(WebClient.create(mockWebServer.url("/").toString()));

@AfterEach
void tearDown() throws IOException {
    mockWebServer.shutdown();
}

@Test
void call() throws InterruptedException {
    mockWebServer.enqueue(
            new MockResponse()
                    .setResponseCode(200)
                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .setBody("{\"y\": \"value for y\", \"z\": 789}")
    );
    SimpleResponseDto response = apiCaller.callApi().block();
    assertThat(response, is(not(nullValue())));
    assertThat(response.getY(), is("value for y"));
    assertThat(response.getZ(), is(789));

    RecordedRequest recordedRequest = mockWebServer.takeRequest();
    //use method provided by MockWebServer to assert the request header
    recordedRequest.getHeader("Authorization").equals("customAuth");
    DocumentContext context = JsonPath.parse(recordedRequest.getBody().inputStream());
    //use JsonPath library to assert the request body
    assertThat(context, isJson(allOf(
            withJsonPath("$.a", is("value1")),
            withJsonPath("$.b", is(123))
    )));
    }
}
```

However I get the following error when I try to run the test

***ApiCallerTest.java:19: error: cannot access ExternalResource
private final ApiCaller apiCaller = new ApiCaller(WebClient.create(mockWebServer.url("/").toString()));***

Any idea what might be wrong?